# Read a txt file JSON data to publish the messages in Cloud Pub Sub

Tags: text-files, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to publish data to Cloud Pub Sub. Data is in JSON format and is being kept in my local folder. I am not using Cloud Storage and trying to read the pubsub message directly through cloud function. Tested the flow with manually passing messages and the data is getting inserted into Bigquery tables also. Only place i got stuck is, how will i pass a `.txt` file JSON dataset to Cloud PubSub,

**Sample data**

```
{"ID":6,"NAME":"Komal","AGE":22,"ADDRESS":"Assam","SALARY":20000}
```

Can any one pls give me a hint!

I could see various options using cloud storage and all, here i am reading the changed data from DB table, insert those records into 1 dummy table and converting the data from that table to JSON format and writing to a `.txt` file. From here if i could publish the data to pubsub, entire flow will get completed

If i manually pass like below, the data will get inserted

> gcloud pubsub topics publish pubsubtopic1 --message

```
{"ID":6,"NAME":"Komal","AGE":22,"ADDRESS":"Assam","SALARY":20000}
```

#### Edit on APRIL 10th

Some how i could achieve the data insert from a .txt file to pubsub using a batch file. But when i call the batch file from PL SQL procedure (DBMS_SCHEDULER), it is throwing error "'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command". But when i call the batch file from the command line, data is getting psuhed to pub sub and to Bigquery table as well.PFB script i am using and the PL SQL code as well. Any help will be really appreciated

#### Batch script & PL SQL code used to call the script

```
@echo off
set file=C:\temp\TEST_EXTRACT.txt
echo %file% >> C:\temp\T1.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%file%) do (ECHO %%A >> C:\temp\T2.txt
ECHO cmd.exe /K cd C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK && gcloud pubsub topics publish pubsubtopic1 --message %%A > C:\temp\T3.txt)

Below mentioned the PL SQL code which is used for calling the batch file

BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB( 
    job_name => 'LOOP_JOB',
    job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
    job_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe',
    --repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI;  BYHOUR=18;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0',
    --start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'EUROPE/LONDON',
    job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
    comments => 'Job to test call out to batch script on Windows',
    auto_drop => FALSE,
    number_of_arguments => 3,
    enabled => FALSE);

SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( 
    job_name => 'LOOP_JOB', argument_position => 1, argument_value => '/q'); 
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( 
    job_name => 'LOOP_JOB', argument_position => 2, argument_value => '/c'); 
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE( 
    job_name => 'LOOP_JOB', argument_position => 3, argument_value => 'C:\temp\loop.bat'); 
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE( 'LOOP_JOB' ); 
END;
/
```

Comment: What programming language are you trying to use to do this? Or are you just wanting to do it strictly via gcloud command line tool?

Comment: Hi Kamal Aboul- Hosn , Language wont be a problem, since i was testing through cloud command line , thought of testing the .txt file data set published through command line only.Basically i wanted automate this process. Really appreciate any help in this

Comment: Is going through a file in JSON a requirement? It seems like there are a lot of unnecessary steps. Why not have whatever is reading the changed data from the DB table write directly to Pub/Sub instead of going through a a dummy table and then a JSON file?

Comment: Your point looks definitely valid, but kindly suggest is there a way we can directly write from DB table data to pubSub in JSON format since i am trying to do mostly through PL/SQL Updated my status on the question i raised. Please take a look. Really appreciate any helps

Answer (score 4):

If you want to easily publish the contents of a single file:

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish ${PUBSUB_TOPIC_NAME} --message "$(cat ${FILE_NAME} | jq -c)"
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your bash script is likely that the gcloud command line tool is not installed on the machine the database is actually running on or is not in the PATH for the environment running the script, so it is not found when your .bat script is run.

That being said, I would highly advise against trying to do data processing in a .bat script and passing it to the command line tool, as it will be highly error prone, and have a large overhead both from going through the inefficient JSON encoding, as well as bringing up and tearing down a publisher client for every message.  Instead, I would suggest that you look at exporting the data in CSV format instead, and using one of the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) to read this file and publish to Cloud Pub/Sub.  That can still be triggered from the database cron job as you mentioned below, and will be much more efficient as well as more testable.

Answer (score 0):

If the Json data that you've got in your file is an array, then you can publish to the topic every entry of that array with the following command:

```
jq -c ".[]" json_array.json | xargs -t -I {} gcloud pubsub topics publish yourTopic --message {}
```

Make sure you have `jq` installed, while `xargs` is more common.